# Notepad++ difficult regular expression

Tags: notepad++, regex

let's say I have text documents that look like that

```
1   
M1577682
Wayne   United States   Minnesota   Minneapolis 55  2019-10-31 14:51:05
2   
M1527197
henrik  Denmark Sjelland    Koge    52  2019-10-31 14:29:53
3   
M3455913
Kim Canada  Ontario London  61  2019-10-30 21:36:03
4   
M2040689
shapo   Germany Hesse-Darmstadt Frankfurt   45  2019-10-31 13:19:12
```

I need to make a line from that text that looks like this.

```
M1577682,M1527197,M3455913,M2040689
```

I have found that this ^(?!.*M1577682)(.*?)$ will select anything that does not contain M1577682.

And this \bM\w{7,} will select any words that start with M and have 7 or more letters after that. (still selects Minnesota and Minneapolis too, I can't fix that)

So can I somehow merge those two regex thingies together to select everything that doesn't start with M and has 7 digits(letters) and replace it with a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go, after that you have to remove manualy the last comma.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:(?:(?!M\d{7}).)*|\G)(M\d{7})(?:(?!M\d{7}).)*`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?:             # non capture group
        (?!         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
            M       # the letter M
            \d{7}   # 7 digits
        )           # end lookahead
        .           # any character
    )*              # end group, may appaear 0 or more times
  |                 # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
)                   # end group
(                   # group 1
    M               # the letter M
    \d{7}           # 7 digits
)                   # end group 1
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
        M           # the letter M
        \d{7}       # 7 digits
    )               # end lookahead
    .               # any character
)*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

***Note:*** You may be want to add word boundaries, if it's the case replace `M\d{7}` with `\bM\d{7}\b` everywhere in the regex.

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Oh this is wonderful, works perfectly for me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Borschik: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is "M" followed by 7 sequential digits, we can try to match what we want to keep and negate it using the following regex:

`^(?!M[0-9]{7}).*`

where the inner portion is

- `M` - Matches "M" exactly
- `[0-9]` - Matches a single character in the list containing the
  digits zero to nine.
- `{7}`- A quantifier for the above list (match 7 digits)

and the outer portion is the negative lookahead. [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/U0x5ae/1)!

Comment: And how do you get the expected result?

Comment: Thank you, it helped me understand how do the regexes behave. I can make it work in conjunction with a second step.